# Navbar not selecting section items on scroll - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created an html page using html5, css3 and bootstrap. Issue is that the navbar menu is not highlighting/selecting the items that are pointing to sections. I want that when I scroll down to other sections, the navbar should automatically highlight them in its menu. Here is snippet:

```css
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  padding: 50px;
}

.cl_white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>

   <section id="home" style="background: url(header.jpg); background-size=100% 100%;" class="text-center cl_white">
    <h1>Zeshan Sajid | Portfolio</h1>
    <p class="lead">Hey Welcome there! Let just read myselft and then contact me for your projects and tasks that you want me to finish on the basis of professinality and perfection with the blend of magical skills. You are always welcome to contact me and ask your queries, as I am available to help you all the time in this regard. Thanks. </p>
   </section>
   <section id = "work"></section>
   <section id = "contact"></section>
</body>
      
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 CSS with Bootstrap 4 JS?

Answer (score 0):

i added smooth behavior css for smooth scroll and give 100vh height to p tag for scroll spy view only.

**Explanation**

you need to add `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarNav"` in body tag and after match data-target id with `navbar-collapse` and `button's data-target`.

```css
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
p{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarNav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#project">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </nav>
  <div>
    <h4 id="home">@fat</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi expedita non fuga sint, cumque, commodi, quia iure quidem dolore repudiandae aut ducimus, at impedit. Dolore tempore esse nisi placeat reprehenderit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit perferendis neque, cupiditate tempora in, facere ad voluptate! Rerum incidunt provident totam voluptate molestiae dolore distinctio eaque officiis ex facilis.</p>
    <h4 id="about">@mdo</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum obcaecati ut pariatur corrupti, nisi iure tempora, consectetur impedit saepe. Distinctio soluta eos odio accusamus tempore iusto nam sunt, corporis quam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi itaque, voluptates possimus dolorem tempora ipsam eum consectetur natus in iste odio officiis, doloribus consequuntur accusantium aut illum dicta deleniti a!</p>
    <h4 id="project">one</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum sed debitis ab aspernatur itaque dignissimos ducimus quam, voluptate esse illum dolore vitae voluptatum nemo consequuntur earum molestiae. Natus, perferendis, quaerat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate eveniet minus facere repellendus quaerat cum maxime molestiae repudiandae soluta nobis eum, fugiat, dolores reiciendis aliquam molestias nostrum, asperiores optio sequi?</p>
    <h4 id="contact">two</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis eaque repellat ex modi veritatis quas. Aperiam, maxime numquam sint provident vel fugit suscipit commodi pariatur perferendis quas ipsam! Unde, neque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere illo commodi aut quae, hic porro. Consectetur voluptate, perspiciatis amet laborum tempora ab, provident ipsam, sequi labore sunt est molestiae libero.</p>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't forgot to consider up-vote and check this answer as best answer for you by clicking on right arrow, thanks!